# Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator: Building Error 2011

Tags: windows, layout, keyboard

I want to make a custom keyboard layout for WIndows 10. But after adding some new symbols I can't build dll package for them.
The message body:

```
Error 2011 (...\.\tmpSlaTur.txt, line 42):
  There are not enough columns in the layout list.
```

I can't find any solutions for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue. This error message seems to appear whenever I have anything on the CTRL+SHIFT layer. I wasn't able to solve the issue, except for keeping this layer empty.